# How come the following characters are displayed in ISO-8859-1?

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

I have the following html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
    会意字 / 會意字 huìyìzì
</body>
```

When I run it in firefox, it displays the Chinese characters just fine. How come it works with the ISO-8859-1 characterset? I thought you needed UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your successful rendering:

[image: Not rendering correctly in Firefox]

… but HTML 5 defines [a fairly complex character encoding detection method](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding) which doesn't pay any attention to `<meta>` until step 9.

In general, you should avoid encodings other than UTF-8 and definitely should not lie about the encoding of the document.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable explanation is that the document is in fact UTF-8 encoded and the browser treats it that way, despite the `meta` tag. According to [HTML5 encoding sniffing algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding), which largely reflects browser behavior, the `meta` tag is ignored if any of the following is true:

- The user has instructed (via e.g. a View → Encoding command) the browser to use a specific encoding.
- The page starts with bytes that represent the Byte Order Mark in UTF-8 or UTF-16. In practice, it starts that way if the file was saved in an editor with a command like “Save as UTF-8 (with BOM)”.
- HTTP headers specify an encoding in a `Content-Type` header.

You can find out which of these is the cause by using e.g. [Rex Swain’s HTTP viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html). It lets you see both the HTTP response headers and the actual data as bytes. Developer Tools in browsers have similar features.